# GitHub Actions Docker Service Container >25GB Cannot Be Loaded

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am attempting to use the [minus34/gnafloader](https://hub.docker.com/r/minus34/gnafloader) Docker container in a GitHub Actions workflow. The container is 21-25 Gb when uncompressed which causes the workflow to run out of storage and crash.

```
name: Address Testing
on: workflow_call
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services: 
      db: 
        image: minus34/gnafloader:latest
```

I then looked into deleting some of the pre-installed software so that there would be enough storage space using [easimon/maximize-build-space](https://github.com/easimon/maximize-build-space). The problem I encountered with this approach was that the services are always started first so the files aren't deleted until after the container is pulled.

```
name: Address Testing
on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Maximize build space
        uses: easimon/maximize-build-space@master
        with:
          root-reserve-mb: 512
          swap-size-mb: 1024
          remove-dotnet: 'true'
          remove-android: 'true'
      - uses: docker://minus34/gnafloader:latest
```

So I was wondering if there were any workarounds to pull the docker container after the additional storage space has been made available?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on _"the services are always started first so the files aren't deleted until after the container is pulled."_? What are "the services"? What does "first" mean? First before what? Why can't the services be deleted before the container is pulled? What dictates this relationship? And what have you tried next to trying `uses: easimon/maximize-build-space@master`? How long are you learning using that specific  action? Do you think this could be a configuration problem?

Comment: @hakre GitHub Actions Service Containers are described here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers

Comment: Given your specific use case, using `services` may not work. You can simply `docker pull` and `docker run` in the next step after running the cleanup step. Have you tried it? You might need to run it in detached mode i.e. with `-d` flag and add some sleep after it to make sure it is up before proceeding to the next step.

Comment: Ah, now I see it, `services` is only in the not-working workflow file. For debugging, i'd run postgres as a service and then use option 3. If importing the downloaded files hits the size limit you know its too big. Otherwise you know you've made it.

Comment: @hakre yeah that will probably work

Comment: @Azeem is docker installed by default?

Comment: @LukePrior: Yes, docker is [preinstalled](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#tools).

Comment: @Azeem I gave it a try but still seems to be erroring: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: write /var/lib/postgresql/15/main/base/5/17875: no space left on device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of running the docker container using `docker run` as suggested by @Azeem after additional space has been cleared using [easimon/maximize-build-space](https://github.com/easimon/maximize-build-space).

One thing to note with easimon/maximize-build-space is that by default the location of docker containers is reduced to 0 and needs to be manually set using `root-reserve-mb`.

```
name: Address Testing
on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Maximize build space
        uses: easimon/maximize-build-space@master
        with:
          root-reserve-mb: 35000
          swap-size-mb: 1024
          remove-dotnet: 'true'
          remove-android: 'true'
      - name: Docker
        run: |
          docker pull minus34/gnafloader:latest
          docker run -d --publish=5433:5432 minus34/gnafloader:latest
```

Comment: Yep, all seems to be ok after upping the root reserve a bit.

Comment: @LukePrior: If it runs with `docker run`, have you given it a try it runs with `uses` again as well? Seeing that the root drive requires the free-space I'm pretty sure `uses: docker://minus34/gnafloader:latest` would also benefit from that.